# Can I start to develop my website on WordPress.org before purchasing my web hosting?

Tags: domain, hosting, design

I am currently in the process of starting a blog, but as of right now I only want to start designing the site, creating the layout before I go live. Is there a way that I could do that on WordPress.org, and then place my domain name to my web hoster? I only ask because I don't want to purchase everything at once and waste the money that I spent on web hosting while my site wasn't active yet due to the design process

Comment: The only thing you can do on wordpress.org is downloading the code. Then you have to run it on a server, locally or hosted elsewhere.

Comment: have a look at https://wordpress.org/support/article/installing-wordpress-on-your-own-computer/